# Calling web service from nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-services, request

I intend to call a java web service using npm's request module. However, I don't want to wait for the java web service to complete processing and send the response. Rather, want my client to be done once it calls the web service. Any advice on what would be the best way to achieve this? Should I be using timeout or rather my java web service handle this? Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Please add more detail. Whichever Java web service you are calling, I am presuming that it is just a domain(ip) you are calling therefore it doesn't matter which language you are using on other end.

Answer (score 1):

you can use promise version of request here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise